# variable indefinida en petición

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos de empleados, busca en la base de datos e imprime los detalles, el paso siguiente es que se abra un página con los detalles del empleado, pero tengo problemas con esto, me dice que es una variable indefinida.

este es mi código de búsqueda

```
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="searchform" id="searchform">
<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
<?php

require_once('./controllers/Employee.php');

$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbase = "employees_assign"; 
$table = "tbl_employees";

$search_term = $_POST["str"];

$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbase);

if ($connect->connect_error){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $connect->connect_error;
}
else{
  if(empty($search_term)){
    echo "<h2> You haven't search anyone </h2>";
  }
  else{
    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM tbl_employees WHERE emp_fname LIKE '%$search_term%' OR emp_lname LIKE '%$search_term%' OR CONCAT(emp_fname,' ',emp_lname) LIKE '%$search_term%'";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<a href='views/emp_detail.php' <div id='result'> <h2><img src='images/".$row['emp_image']."'/> <br><h2>You Search " . $row["emp_fname"] . " " . $row["emp_lname"] . " And works in  " .$row["emp_job"]."<br />" . "<br / > </h2> </div></a>";  



      }
    }else{
      echo "<h3> We don't have anyone with that name :( </h3>";
    }
  };
};

?>
```

y los detalles

```
<div id="content">

<?php


while($emp = mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?id='.$emp['emp_id'].'">'.$emp['emp_fname'].' '.$emp['emp_lname'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
</div>
```

tendría que reconocer el id para reconocer el empleado, y es en esto en lo que estoy fallando.

También me dice que no reconocer la variable $str en la búsqueda.

Gracias

Comment: Supongo que en los dos `while` que tienes estás trabajando con el mismo conjunto de resultados obtenido aquí: `$result = $connect->query($sql);`. Si es así, tienes un ligero error de enfoque en la lógica de tu programa, ya que estás haciendo dos `fetch`, uno aquí: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){` y otro aquí: `while($emp = mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {` este último, por lo demás, es erróneo, ya que no hay ningún conjunto de resultados en la variable `$employees`. Puedes guardar todo en el primer `while`, aunque luego una parte la presentes aparte...

Comment: Deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla. Este código tiene deficiencias de seguridad y podría ser vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando recién cargas la página, te muestra el formulario pero no has realizado ninguna petición `POST` por lo que esa pantalla inicial no debe ejecutar la consulta.

Debieras comprobar si está seteada `$_POST["str"]`.

```
if(isset($_POST["str"]) {
  $search_term = $_POST["str"];

  ... consulta e impresión de los resultados ...

}
```

Además, veo que estás interpolando la variable `$search_term` directamente en la query.

Si alguien busca por el empleado `juan%'; DROP TABLE tbl_employees; --` te puede borrar la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]